# Why is Insert happening rather than update on Upsert call?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have used the following code . Here It is creating new records rather than updating the existing One. I need to update the record . Pls suggest.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case"  extensions="QueueController" sidebar="false" showHeader="true" showChat="false" >
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Select A Queue">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4" title="Select A Queue">
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            Select Queue :
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
               <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!queue}">
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!QueueList}"></apex:selectOptions>
               </apex:selectList> 
           </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4"  >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveCase}" id="save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
           <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>



public class QueueController {
   public List<Group> GroupNameList{get;set;}

    private final Case caseObj{get;set;}

    public String queue {get;set;}

    public QueueController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
              this.caseObj = (Case)controller.getRecord();
              GroupNameList = new List<Group>();

           // update this.caseObj;
        }

     public PageReference saveCase(){
            caseobj.ownerid = queue;
            upsert caseobj;
            PageReference ref = new PageReference('/'+caseobj.id);
            return ref;
}
    public List<SelectOption> QueueList 
    {
        get
        {
            GroupNameList  = [select g.Id, g.Name from Group g where Type = 'Queue'];

            QueueList = new List<SelectOption>();

            for(Group temp : GroupNameList)
            {
                QueueList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.Name));
            }
            return QueueList;
        }
        set;
        }

}
```

Comment: Try remove the `final` keyword when defining your `caseObj` variable

Comment: I am still getting a new case created... while I just want to update my record.

Comment: If you do `update` instead of `upsert`, does that update the same record or you're getting errors?

Comment: I am getting error for that

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []
Error is in expression '{!saveCase}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page mic_vf_escalate

Class.QueueController.saveCase: line 18, column 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you opening the VF page with an id in the query string?  If you aren't, then the

```
  this.caseObj = (Case)controller.getRecord();
```

will generate a new case. That would be my guess as to what is happening. Especially if the error is about not being able to update the record due to missing id.

Comment: can u pls suggest how can we update it ?

Comment: When you call the page, you need to specify the id of the case you are trying to update, something like this: /apex/caseQueue?id=500xxxxxxxxxxxx Or, if you are overriding the view or edit pages for the case, this is done for you.